# Python online data modification using ajax

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask, jinja2

Python3(FLASK) application containing FORM and SELECT.
When selecting a specific position in the SELECT, the contents of the FORM should change without reloading the page.
I wanted to use AJAX for this, but I don’t understand how to change the data on the page after Python returned the array to the page.
Python receives data and renders layout using FLASK

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    try:
        for i in DB.check_connect():
            if i[0] == 1:
                get_ratio = DB.get_ratio()
                get_office_group = DB.get_office_group()
                get_rates_for_current_office = DB.get_rates_for_current_office(0)
                lenth_rates = len(get_rates_for_current_office)
                #We get the value from the selected SELECT and return an array of new values.
                if request.method == "POST":
                    id = request.form['id']
                    get_rates_for_current_office = DB.get_rates_for_current_office(id)
                    return get_rates_for_current_office
            else:
                print('Cannot connect DB')
        resp = make_response(render_template('index.html', get_ratio=get_ratio, get_office_group=get_office_group,  get_rates_for_current_office = get_rates_for_current_office, lenth_rates = lenth_rates))
        return resp
    except Exception as error:
        print("An exception occurred:", error)
        return render_template('login.html')
```

HTML page

```
        <select class="form-select mt-3"  name="office_group">
            {% for item in get_office_group %}
                <option data-id="{{ item[0] }}" value="{{ item[0] }}">{{ item[1] }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
...............
                 <tbody>
                    {% for i in range(0, lenth_rates) %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ get_ratio[i][0] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ get_ratio[i][3] }} {{ get_ratio[i][1] }}/{{ get_ratio[i][2] }}</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control"  name="buy_{{ get_ratio[i][4] }}" value='{{ get_rates_for_current_office[i][0] }}'/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control"  name="sell_{{ get_ratio[i][4] }}" value='{{ get_rates_for_current_office[i][1] }}'/></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
```

AJAX to pass Python the value selected in a SELECT.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            $ids = $(this).children('option:selected').data('id')
            $.ajax({
                url: '/',
                data: {id:$ids},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(get_rates_for_current_office){
                    console.log(get_rates_for_current_office);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Is it possible to make online changes to data on a page without reloading using Python (preferably) or an additional module?

Comment: I don't follow your logic on an exception. Why would it redirect to `login.html`? You can of course update parts of the page with AJAX but this redirect throws a spanner in the works, particularly when I can't see how you're even validating the user login in the first place

Comment: I cut out part of the authorization logic from the example so as not to clutter it with unnecessary information.

Comment: Ok, and the other question I have is where is the `select`? There isn't one in your template

Comment: roganjosh, thanks, you're right. Added

Comment: I started putting an answer together for this but it fell apart when I realised just how much of the logic is missing from your question. I'll leave that [here](https://dpaste.org/SiMEb) but there is too much that doesn't add up in the question for me to continue

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In the end I did this https://www.vrsofttech.com/python-flask/python-flask-get-data-jquery-ajax-post